# Unable to debug AWS Lambda Functions in Visual Studio Code. Code Lens info not visible

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda

I am following the steps on the link below to install, setup and debug AWS Lambda functions with Visual Studio Code.

Steps: `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/create-sam.html`

Under "Run and Debug your AWS SAM application", point 2, it says *"if the CodeLenses are not already visible, select the AWS Explorer icon in the Activity Bar to activate it."*

This does not work for me - i.e. I am not able to see the code lens links and so cannot "Debug Locally".  I have tried this on my PC, as well as on a Macbook Pro.

Any ideas, about how to get debugging working with AWS Lambda functions and Visual Studio Code, greatly appreciated.

**Question: How do I ensure that the CodeLens becomes visible in Visual Studio Code, so that I can debug locally against AWS Lambda functions?**

Comment: In VSCode under settings enable --> Enable SAM hints in source file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

**Use the Python: Configure Unit Tests command on the Command Palette.**

I found the answer here: `https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/unit-testing`

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the language mode to javascript (Babel) and then the codelens options became visible above my handlers.

Spent 2 hours trying to figure this out lol

Comment: hi, it's better to post this as a comment instead of answer, keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 0):

Just select a Python environment on the status bar down to your left. It took a while for me to finally understand it